# How to make Application.Run() testable

Tags: c#, winforms, system-testing

I am currently writing system tests for a legacy windows forms application.

In my test, I call the `Program.Main()` method, which in turn calls `Application.Run(new MainForm());` at some point.

Is there a way to replace Application.Run() with something that I can control?

Specifically, I need to be able to stop the execution and catch unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify Program.Main to accept a form as an input parameter, with a default of MainForm. Reference types can't have non-null defaults but we can accomplish the same thing by using two prototypes:

```
class Program
{
    //Normal entry point
    static public void Main()
    {
        Main(new MainForm());
    }

    //Internal & test entry point
    static public void Main(Form form)
    {
        DoSomeSetup();
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

When you run the program in the normal way, it'll use a `MainForm`.

But when you run it from your test project, you can call it like this:

```
Program.Main(new FormICanControl());
```

And then you can control it.

```
//Arrange
var t = new TestForm();

//Act
Program.Main(t);
t.ExecuteSomeTest();

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(t.ResultCode, 0, "Test failed.");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To "stop the execution", you can ask Main thread to exit by calling Application.ExitThread() and in dreadful situations when it does't respond you may kill the Main thread with `.Abort()` as a last resort.
2. The exceptions won't be automatically collected for you anywhere, but you can catch them in a process of testing using

> Application.ThreadExceptionHandler
>
> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

3. Testing a real-life app without `Application` might be a problem because people often do some tricks by calling Application.DoEvents(..) and doing other stuff with messages pump.